# Resize GridView Items in UWP

Tags: c#, uwp, uwp-xaml

I'm looking for a way to resize the width of my `GridView` items programmatically. I have a `<GridView>` that uses a `<DataTemplate>` and one of the `GridView` item's children has a width set. I'm looking to change that width on a button click.

My initial attempt was going to use an integer set in the code behind which would be updated with the new width and then figuring out a way to refresh the `GridView` but I can't access the integer due to `<DataTemplate>` changing the context/scope for `x:Bind`. Is there a better way to achieve this?

```
<GridView x:Name="gridView1" ItemsSource="{x:Bind Orders}">
    <GridView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:DataType="data:Order">
            <RelativePanel Width="200"></RelativePanel>
            </RelativePanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </GridView.ItemTemplate>
</GridView>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your requirement, you could bind `RelativePanel` Width with specified `Source`. I have created a setting class that use to management items Width. Then init a setting instance in `Application.Resources`.

```
public class Setting : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private double _itemWidth = 200;
    public double ItemWidth
    {
        get { return _itemWidth; }
        set { _itemWidth = value; OnPropertyChanged(); }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        this.PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

**Application.Resources**

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <local:Setting x:Key="Setting"/>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

**Usage**

```
<GridView  x:Name="gridView1" ItemsSource="{x:Bind Orders}" ItemClick="GridView1_ItemClick" IsItemClickEnabled="True">
    <GridView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:DataType="x:String">
            <RelativePanel Width="{Binding ItemWidth,Source={StaticResource Setting}}" Background="SeaGreen" >
                <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind }"/>
            </RelativePanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </GridView.ItemTemplate>
</GridView>
```

If you want to update the items width you could modify the Setting Width property in button click event.

```
private void GridView1_ItemClick(object sender, ItemClickEventArgs e)
{
    ((Setting)Application.Current.Resources["Setting"]).ItemWidth = 500;
}
```

---

**Update**

Move to Page Resources

```
<Page.Resources>
    <local:Setting x:Key="Setting"/>
</Page.Resources>
```

**Usage**

```
private void GridView1_ItemClick(object sender, ItemClickEventArgs e)
{
    ((Setting)this.Resources["Setting"]).ItemWidth = 500;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm running into an exception when implementing: `{System.Reflection.TargetParameterCountException: Parameter count mismatch.` The main difference I can see in my implementation is that my App.xaml is setup like this: `<Application.Resources>
        <XamlControlsResources xmlns="using:Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls">
            <local:Setting x:Key="Setting"/>
        </XamlControlsResources>
    </Application.Resources>` is that correct?

Comment: Please try remove `XamlControlsResources `.

Comment: I'm using `<muxc:NavigationView>` for compatibility and the app doesn't run without the `XamlControlsResources`. Is that the only way?

Comment: You could move  `<local:Setting x:Key="Setting"/>` to your page resource.

Comment: I was able to get it to work with page resources but the gridview doesn't update after changing `ItemWidth`, do I need to refresh the gridview somehow?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187219/discussion-between-nico-zhu-msft-and-arvinkx).